# how could i use ETag in smarty?

Tags: php, smarty, etag

I use smarty as my template engine and YSlow ( Firefox addon  ) report me that my Etag flag is "F" But i use smarty.
how could i use Etag with smarty and my main tpl is framework.tpl and all other templates assign to it

Comment: AFAIK ETags don't really have much to do with Smarty...

Comment: The [Best Practices for Speeding Up Your Web Site](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) rather suggest *not* to use *ETag*.

Comment: @Gumbo That's only true for server clusters in the default Apache/IIS configuration. This doesn't apply for small time single-server sites and ETags done right are still enormously useful.

Comment: Note that YSlow score was developed for Yahoo's specific situation; ETags are in general not *necessary* (although they can be useful, when well combined with the other caching directives). In other words, it's an informative score, not hard rules that you desperately need to conform to. See also this: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/08/yslow-yahoos-problems-are-not-your-problems.html

Answer (score 1):

If you decide that you actually *need* ETags on your pages (which is different from implementing them just to pass a somewhat arbitrary test), I've had good experience with this (older) script: http://simonwillison.net/2003/Apr/23/conditionalGet/

Note that this is not really Smarty-specific, as Smarty deals with page templates; this whole "conditional request" business (with ETag and Last-Modified and whatnot) happens in HTTP *headers*, so the code above is just plain PHP.

You need to determine the last modification time of your resource (which may be different from file modification - e.g. when was the last time the relevant part of the database changed?), and pass it to `doConditionalGet($timestamp)`; it will then either send a 304 and terminate, or return back to you (which means you need to do the full page processing, as if there wasn't any conditional request).

Answer (score 0):

Simply but the directive

```
FileETag None
```

in your .htaccess file to disable the ETag header field. YSlow will no longer complain... :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [output filter](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/advanced.features.outputfilters.tpl) in Smarty. Below some ready-to-use code for *ETag*ging:

```
function etag_handler($output)
{
    $etag = md5($output);
    header('ETag: '.$etag);
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH']) && strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH'], $etag) !== FALSE)
    {
        header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 304 Not Modified');
        return '';
    }
    return $output;
}

$smarty->registerFilter('output', 'etag_handler');
```

Put that somewhere before `$smarty->display(...);`.

Note, that with this code the server still computes the output, but if the client has already the identical answer, the server won't send it again, so it's just a network traffic saver. If you want to save computing power in the server, you have to do something else (caching), but you can combine it with ETagging.